# Regarding ternary operator..!

Tags: java

I have condition in my program...

```
boolean allow = false;  
    if RewardsSupport.isRewardsEnabled()) {  
        allow = true;         
    }  
    return (allow);
```

Could you please help me in converting the above code as per ternary operator..!!

Comment: The code you showed doesn't even require ternary operator

Answer (score 11):

What's the point? Why not just have this:

```
return RewardsSupport.isRewardsEnabled()
```

Also, it should be called `areRewardsEnabled()`

Comment: ...and, then, what would be the point of the method? Probably just inline the check everywhere (or store in a local if that improves readability).

Comment: ...and some web application frameworks look specifically for isRewardsEnabled and not areRewardsEnabled which could confuse anyone-- fyi ie JSF views hook ups

Comment: Agreed, most of the frameworks out there expect the `is` prefix. While it would be cool if they could recognize methods that have plural camel case and switch from `is` to `are`, I just don't see that as an important problem that, when solved, would revolutionize the development industry. Another example is Jackson's JSON Serializer and DataNucleus's JDO. They both will expect the `is` prefix.

Answer (score 3):

There's no reason to use the ternary operator here. Since your values are already booleans, you should really just say `return RewardsSupport.isRewardsEnabled();`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a ternary operator for something that involves a Boolean:

```
boolean allow = RewardsSupport.isRewardsEnabled();
```

If you wanted to return, say, an integer, you could do it with a ternary conditional operator like this:

```
int reward = RewardsSupport.isRewardsEnabled() ? rewardAmount : 0;
```

Comment: the condition is like that..public boolean issRewardsEnabled() { String value = posParameterSupport.getStringParamValue( IParameterConstants.REWARDS_ENABLED, "false"); boolean enabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(value); return (enabled); }..please advise me for this..!!

Comment: @Neera You can modify your `if` condition following the second part of my answer as a template: the expression for `true` goes between `?` and `:`, and the expression for `false` goes after `:`.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution utilizes a ternary operator as requested:

```
return RewardsSupport.isRewardsEnabled() ? true : false;
```

Comment: the condition is like that..public boolean issRewardsEnabled() {
  String value = posParameterSupport.getStringParamValue(
    IParameterConstants.REWARDS_ENABLED, "false");
  boolean enabled = Boolean.parseBoolean(value);
  return (enabled);
 }..please advise me for this..!!